# What does "counterstruck" mean?

Tags: meaning

> The earliest traceable specimens of this class are certain
>   ***counterstruck*** imitation silver drachms of Phraates IV,... ([Source](https://digitalcollections.anu.edu.au/bitstream/1885/11274/1/Dobbins_K.W._1972.pdf))

What does "counterstruck" mean?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, [*coin striking*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coining_%28mint%29) is the process of taking a "blank" coin and stamping it with a die so that it now has a picture or other marking on each side.

Secondly, the author(s) of the paper appear to use "counterstruck" and "countermarked" interchangeably, as indicated in this quote from page 27:

> The strikers of the imitation Hermaios coinage were probably
>   also responsible for a group of Arsakid drachms which were
>   **countermarked**, or imitated and then **countermarked** (MA 1-5). It has
>   been demonstrated that the nature of these **counterstrikings** was
>   benign, ...
>   *[emphasis added]*

Finally, a [*countermark*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Countermark) is:

> an additional mark or symbol punched into [a coin] at some point during its career as a circulating coin.

Answer (score 4):

If a coin is counterstruck (or overstruck), an existing coin is treated like a blank so that the old image is obliterated by the new image.

I found the following definition in a [forum for coin collectors](http://www.coincommunity.com/forum/topic.asp?ARCHIVE=true&TOPIC_ID=27547), unfortunately without the original source:

> OVERSTRIKE (COUNTERSTRIKE)- coin struck over an older and usually worn coin used as a planchet [eg, 1804 Bank of England 5-shilling piece struck on a Spanish dollar]

Answer (score 3):

Counterstruck, overstruck, or countermarked means that a coin was 're-used'.

The original coin was freshly stamped with a new pattern/design, over the top of the existing pattern.

Often coins from one authority being re-struck [stamped] to become the currency of a new authority.